# Does the charge of subatomic particle increase if it moves faster?

Tags: particle-physics, electrons, charge, subatomic

Does it stay the same? If it does change, then how much does it change? Is there anything else that can increase the charge of a subatomic particle?

Comment: Why should it change?

Answer (score 0):

Charge is a Lorentz invariant, and the fact that is conserved means there is an underlying symmetry, which is gauge symmetry.
Note that the EM field of a discrete charge produces is frame dependent. At rest, of course, there is a spherically symmetric electric field and no magnetic  field. The moving observer sees the (stronger) electric field squished towards a co-moving plane orthogonal to the direction of motion, and there is a magnetic field too, as the moving charge is a current. For a real world applications of this fact, see transition radiation detectors.